# Call to undefined method App::link()

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I get a "Call to undefined method App::link()" with this view:

```
<?php echo $this->link('Forum index', array('controller' => 'forum', 'action' => 'index')); ?> »
<?php echo $this->link($forumName, array('controller' => 'forum', 'action' => 'view', $forumId)); ?>
```

What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$this->Html->link()` ?

`$this` isn't used much in the view.  Most common would be `$this->Html->` or `$this->Form->`